# Why does Google Analytics show traffic to my website when I open up an AdWords campaign?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I have noticed that every time I open up an AdWords campaign I receive traffic to the landing page for the campaign.  The traffic is a google.com referral traffic.  It's a single page visit with no actions taken and is really throwing off my data.

On the AdWords campaigns dashboard when you first log in it will show you a report that says top landing pages.  I highly suspect this report is creating the hit in analytics.

I don't want to exclude google.com referrals as I understand that they sometimes show up when organic traffic comes from a Google search network provider. But if I can't find a solution I may have to.

Is there any way to disable this behavior in AdWords or filter the AdWords false referrals?